# MySQL Schema_Migrations - Active Record - Update Values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Our legacy Rails app had some broken migrations (so we rolled our migrations) into one large migration, wrote a rake task for it and all works great.

```
desc "Removes all schema migrations and inserts the migration reconstruction"
 task reconstruct_migrations: :environment do
   reconstruction_migration = Dir["db/migrate/*.rb"].find { |migration| migration =~ /reconstruct_database/ }
   file_name = reconstruction_migration.split("/").last
   timestamp = file_name.split("_").first

   puts ">> Resetting migration version to #{timestamp}"

   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tap do |c|
       c.execute("DELETE FROM schema_migrations")
       c.execute("INSERT INTO schema_migrations(version) VALUES ('#{timestamp}')")
     end
  end
end
```

It's a little unorthodox but it's large legacy app and this is situation. However even after rebuilding my migrations, when running a new migration it would fail as the existing MySQL dump would have a conflicting schema_migrations table. It's version column contains all the prior migration timestamps as follows:

```
+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 20081121002510 |
| 20081124055648 |
| 20081124102955 |
| 20081124103008 |
etc....
```

To fix my situation I need to overwrite the values this version column with the current timestamps in my rails app. These are:

```
200507121201
20151111084520
20151117071001
```

---

The table:

```
mysql> show columns from schema_migrations;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| version | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

My attempts to sort this problem:

```
 mysql> UPDATE `schema_migrations` SET `version` = '';
 ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'unique_schema_migrations'


 mysql> alter table schema_migrations drop column version;
 ERROR 1090 (42000): You can't delete all columns with ALTER TABLE; use DROP TABLE instead
```

So in summary how do I go about overwriting the existing values in this column and replacing them with the 3 listed above?

Comment: I don't get it. Why not just drop the migration table in your dump and run the migrations again? Also, if you have a lot of migrations, no need to keep them. You would never roll back that far anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are saying I can just drop the ```schema_migrations``` table, re run the migrations and it will simply repopulate it correctly?

Comment: Yes, if you have all your prior migrations in one migration file. But looking at your code again that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so looks like you need to keep all existing migrations versions in `schema_migrations` since Rails will look for them when you run `rake db:migrate` next time. Basically, if I get it correctly, the only thing that you need to do is adding the timestamp of the reconstruction migration to `schema_migrations`.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes - this is also my understanding - so my question was more about how to use SQL in the MySQL terminal to replace these values!

Comment: If I get it correctly, you don't need to replace anything - you rather need to just insert new migrations versions:
    `INSERT INTO schema_migrations 'version' VALUES ('200507121201'), ('20151111084520'), ('20151117071001')`

Comment: Thanks this solution - was exactly what I required. ```DELETE FROM schema_migrations;``` followed by ```INSERT INTO schema_migrations 'version' VALUES ('200507121201'), ('20151111084520'), ('20151117071001')``` Also for others SQL newbies like myself  ```INSERT INTO schema_migrations VALUES('200507121201');``` to insert single value.